# Ideal LC Tank Circuit

Tags: tank

It is true that connecting an Inductor (L) and a capacitor (C) in parallel provides oscillation? If so, where do you take the output from?

Theoretically it is explained that once we connect L and C in parallel, we assume one of them has some initial energy either in form of voltage (in case of C) or in form of current (in case of L). Then the one initially having energy starts providing it to the one which is bereft of it and as soon as the energy provider element is deprived of its energy, the one which has gained the energy starts providing the energy to the previous provider.

Theoretically that seems ok but where are oscillations in practice? I mean if I have to take the output (i.e the oscillations), where would I connect the load? (assume an ideal tank circuit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (assume an ideal tank circuit)

Even within the context of ideal circuit theory, if one connects a load, e.g., a resistor, to an LC circuit, one no longer has an ideal LC circuit but rather, *an ideal [RLC circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit)*.

For an ideal RLC circuit, any initial energy stored will be dissipated by the resistor; the oscillations decay exponentially with time.

Comment: Well it will decay only to a certain level.  And then the Johnson noise of the resistor will lead to continued oscillations at random phases.  (phase at some late time will be unrelated to some earlier time... times depend on the Q and frequency.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, an ideal resistor is noiseless.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if having some initial energy then a parallel LC will oscillate but this, in reality will be short-lived because the coil will have losses in the form of series resistance and each sine wave cycle will be reduced in amplitude compared to the previous cycle. The capacitor will also have losses but are likely to be less than the inductor and, other losses will be incurred in the creation of a small EM wave which will take energy from the LC and never return it.

If you want to take the output from somewhere than earth one side of the LC circuit and connect an oscilloscope to the other but the problem occurs in getting the initial energy into the coil in order to start the damped oscillation. This could be done with a switch momentarily pushing a dc current through the inductor then, when the switch opens, you'll see a decaying sine wave.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is true that an undamped LC parallel combination is able to produce continuos oscillations. However, it is well known that this is **not** possible with **passive** elements only because of the losses associated with L and C.

On the other hand, you can compensate these losses using an **active** element (opamp) wired as a negative resistance (NIC principle). Hence, if this NIC circuit has a negative input resistance which equals the total losses of the passive LC tank you can design a loss-free resonant circuit (NIC in parallel to the LC tank). More than that, the opamp output provides a low-resistive output node that does not disturb oscillations.

As a modification, you can replace the passive inductance L with another active circuit (active L simulation). This results in one of the well-established two-opamp RC-oscillator concepts.